# java equivalent of c# typeof()

Tags: java, reflection

I'm very new to java. Say I've a xml parser and I'd create object from it. In c# i'd do like:

```
parser p = new parser(typeof(myTargetObjectType));
```

In my parser class I need to know which object I'm making, so that i can throw exception if parsing is not possible.
How to Do the same in jave? I mean how I can take arguments like `typeof(myObject)`

---

I understand every language has it's own way of doing something. I'm asking what's way in java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java has the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class as the entry point for any reflection operation on Java types.

> Instances of the class `Class` represent classes and interfaces in a
>   running Java application

To get the type of an object, represented as a `Class` object, you can invoke the [`Object#getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method inherited by all reference types.

> Returns the runtime class of this `Object`.

You cannot do this (invoke `getClass()`) with primitive types. However, primitive types also have an associated `Class` object. You can do

```
int.class
```

for instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UnsupportedClass myObject = new UnsupportedClass();
    Parser parser = new Parser(myObject.getClass());
  }
}

class Parser {
  public Parser(Class<?> objectType) {
    if (UnsupportedClass.class.isAssignableFrom(objectType)) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Objects of type UnsupportedClass are not allowed");
    }
  }
}

class UnsupportedClass {}
```

Or since you have the instance of the object, this is easier:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(myObject);

public Parser(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof UnsupportedClass) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Objects of type UnsupportedClass are not allowed");
    }
}
```